# select elements from jsonb postgres array

Tags: arrays, json, postgresql, window-functions, unnest

i have this jsonb in my database.
I need to show the element that is in state 1 if and only if the previous element is in state 3

I need to make the query that brings me the element that meets the condition.

is posible with postgres ?

```
 [
    {
        "state": 3,
        "activity": "EJECUCIÓN",
        "final_date": "2020-02-24",
        "activity_id": 1,
        "current_days": -7,
        "initial_date": "2020-02-24",

    },
    {
        "state": 1,
        "activity": "REVISIÓN",
        "final_date": "2020-02-25",
        "activity_id": 2,
        "current_days": 0,
        "initial_date": "2020-02-25",

    },
    {
        "state": 0,    
        "activity": "RECEPCIÓN",
        "final_date": "2020-02-27",
        "activity_id": 4,
        "current_days": 0,
        "initial_date": "2020-02-27"


    } ]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can unnest the json array to rows in a subquery, then use window function to retrieve the "previous" array element. All the is then left to do is filtering.

Assuming that your json(b!) data is stored in column `js` of table `mytable`, you could phrase this as:

```
select x.obj
from mytable t
cross join lateral (
    select x.obj, lag(obj) over(order by rn) lag_obj
    from jsonb_array_elements(t.js) with ordinality as x(obj, rn)
) x
where (obj ->> 'state')::int = 1 and (lag_obj ->> 'state')::int = 3
```

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_12&fiddle=3bbb835d6805176a852a434474d0389d)**

Comment: Note that if the json-array itself is not sorted but the order should be derived from `"initial_date"` or `"final_date"` that can easily be done by changing the `(ORDER BY rn)` to e.g `(ORDER BY x.obj->>'initial_date')`.

Comment: and if the object with state1 is the first it has no previous object it should show it too

[
    {
        "state": 1,
        "activity": "EJECUCIÓN",
       

    },
    {
        "state": 0,
        "activity": "REVISIÓN",
     

    },
    {
        "state": 0,    
        "activity": "RECEPCIÓN",
      


    } ]

Comment: @DarioPaez: ok so just change the `where` clause to: `where (obj ->> 'state')::int = 1 and ((lag_obj ->> 'state')::int = 3 or lag_obj is null)`.

Answer (score 1):

You will need to explode the json to do this:

```
with invars as (
  select 1 as id, ' [
    {
        "state": 3,
        "activity": "EJECUCIÓN",
        "final_date": "2020-02-24",
        "activity_id": 1,
        "current_days": -7,
        "initial_date": "2020-02-24"

    },
    {
        "state": 1,
        "activity": "REVISIÓN",
        "final_date": "2020-02-25",
        "activity_id": 2,
        "current_days": 0,
        "initial_date": "2020-02-25"

    },
    {
        "state": 0,    
        "activity": "RECEPCIÓN",
        "final_date": "2020-02-27",
        "activity_id": 4,
        "current_days": 0,
        "initial_date": "2020-02-27"


    } ]'::jsonb as jcol
), expand as (
  select i.id, 
         j.obj->>'state' as this_state,
         lag(j.obj->>'state') 
           over (partition by id
                     order by rn) as last_state,
         j.obj
    from invars i
         cross join lateral 
           jsonb_array_elements(jcol) 
             with ordinality as j(obj, rn)
)
select *
  from expand
 where this_state = '1' 
   and last_state = '3'
;
┌────┬────────────┬────────────┬─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ id │ this_state │ last_state │                                                                 obj                                                                 │
├────┼────────────┼────────────┼─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┤
│  1 │ 1          │ 3          │ {"state": 1, "activity": "REVISIÓN", "final_date": "2020-02-25", "activity_id": 2, "current_days": 0, "initial_date": "2020-02-25"} │
└────┴────────────┴────────────┴─────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
(1 row)
```